# Concatenate different variables with number values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have different variables with string values, that I simply want to concatenate into one number.

For example I have the following variables:

```
pupil_id, class, term, id should result into Pupil_class_id
   23       8      3    23                         8323
```

I tried:

```
Select
    pupil_id, class, term, id,
    concat(class + term + id) as Pupil_class_id
from 
    school
```

and I tried

```
concat(class, term, id) as Pupil_class_id
from school
```

and I tried

```
concat('class', 'term' 'id') as Pupil_class_id
from school
```

I would have thought that solution 1 or 2 work, but they don't

Any suggestions?

No errors, but also no result, just 0

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean.  Do you mean you want to concat the strings 'class', 'term' and 'id' into 'class_term_id'?  Or did you want to concat a few numbers variables into a string?  Or what.  Can you make your question cleaner please?

Comment: I have: the variables class, term, id                 
 class =8, term = 3 , id= 23. I want to get the new variable: Pupil_class_id  8323     Essentially, what function adds the variables to create a new variable- not a sum, but just put all these numbers next to each other in one variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with using a comma (`,`) as separator, and specifying the column names **without** single quotes is the way to do. I cannot reproduce any problems with that - not sure why you say this didn't work for you....

Try this (I'm using SQL Server 2016, but this should work from 2012 on):

```
DECLARE @Input TABLE (pupil_id INT, class INT, term INT, id INT)

INSERT INTO @Input (pupil_id, class, term, id)
VALUES (23, 8, 3, 23)

SELECT
    CONCAT(class, term, id)
FROM
    @Input
```

I get this output:

```
(No column name)
8323
```

which - if I understand correctly - is what you're looking for.

The only reason this might *not* work is if you're using an "old" database, e.g. if your database compatibility level is set to an earlier version of SQL Server. Was this database "upgraded" from a previous version of SQL Server?

Try this:

```
SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
```

What value do you get?? SQL Server 2012 should be "110" - do you have a lower value?